# Push file to Bitbucket 'Downloads' section from Bamboo

Tags: git, bitbucket, bamboo

Is it possible to push a file to the 'Downloads' section of a Bitbucket repo from Bamboo? I.e., if I make Bamboo run a script that generates a zip file, can Bamboo then push that zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bamboo doesn't have built-in support for such operation.
But it should be easy to achieve it by final Script task with some curl commands.

According to scenario described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads-872124574.html) it's possible to upload artifact by REST call. So you need to create plan variable with Bitbucket Cloud permissions and add last task of your build to run curl command from article. Hope it helps. If you need more details how to configure Bamboo for such flow - just let me know